# Oracle Apex: Call a trigger from Table B from a trigger in Table A

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle-apex

I am trying to perform trigger action from table A that lead to trigger action in table B, but I am getting the following errors.

```
ORA-04091: table IMIT.INFRA_ASSETS_MASTER is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "IMIT.SUBNET_LOOKUP_DELETE_TRIGGER", line 15
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'IMIT.SUBNET_LOOKUP_DELETE_TRIGGER'
ORA-06512: at "IMIT.INFRA_MASTER_DELETE_TRIGGER", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'IMIT.INFRA_MASTER_DELETE_TRIGGER'
```

So when I delete a item from the table it calls this trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "INFRA_MASTER_DELETE_TRIGGER" 
   before delete on infra_assets_master
   for each row
begin
   DELETE FROM SUBNET_LOOKUP WHERE LINK_ID = :old.ID AND DEF_ID = 3;
   INSERT INTO HISTORY (IT_TABLE,ITEM_ID,ACTION_TYPE,ACTION)VALUES('INFRA_ASSETS_MASTER',:old.ID,3,CONCAT(CONCAT('Infrastructure Asset  ', :old.ASSET_ID),' deleted'));
end;
```

which will end up deleting another record in another table, calling the delete trigger in that table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER  "SUBNET_LOOKUP_DELETE_TRIGGER" 
   before delete on subnet_lookup
   for each row
declare
  v_def varchar2(255);
  v_link varchar2(255);
  v_subnet varchar2(255);
  v_sen varchar2(255);
begin
   select NAME into v_def from subnet_lookup_definition where id = :old.DEF_ID;
   v_sen := 'Remove Link Between ';
   if :old.DEF_ID = 1 then
      select hostname into v_link from servers_master where id = :old.LINK_ID;
      v_sen := concat(v_sen,concat(concat('Server ''', v_link),''''));
   end if;

   if :old.DEF_ID = 3 then
      select asset_id into v_link from infra_assets_master where id = :old.LINK_ID;
      if v_link IS NULL then
        select hostname into v_link from infra_assets_master where id = :old.LINK_ID;
      end if;
      v_sen := concat(v_sen,concat(concat('Infrastructure Assets ''', v_link),''''));
   end if;

   if :old.DEF_ID = 4 then
      select asset_id into v_link from assets_master where id = :old.LINK_ID;
      v_sen := concat(v_sen,concat(concat('IT Assets ''', v_link),''''));
   end if;

   select address into v_subnet from subnet where id = :old.SUBNET_ID;

   v_sen := concat(concat(v_sen, concat(' to ', v_subnet)),' has been deleted');

   insert into HISTORY (IT_TABLE, ITEM_ID,ACTION_TYPE, ACTION) VALUES ('SUBNET_LOOKUP',:old.SUBNET_ID,3,v_sen);
end;
```

I don't understand what is the problem.

how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> "what is the problem"

When you delete `infra_assets_master` your trigger on the table executes a delete of child records in `subnet_lookup`. But that table also has a trigger which looks up its parent `infra_assets_master` record. Which is **the record you are deleting**. Oracle doesn't understand how to resolve this confusion so it hurls the mutating table error.

> "how do I resolve this issue?"

By removing the cyclic dependency. You need to change your business logic to avoid the query on `infra_assets_master`. Exactly how you do this is your problem, because it is your business logic not ours, but essentially you need to find a way to populate the history table with information from only the table which is being deleted. Alternative put all the SUBNET_LOOKUP_DELETE_TRIGGER logic in a stored procedure called from INFRA_MASTER_DELETE_TRIGGER.